# Framer motion exit animation also plays on mapped react div elements

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I am new to Framer Motion, and I can't figure out this problem.
I am using React and I have an array of objects that I .map() through.
For each object, it will make a div.

Here is my problem: I made this div a motion.div and I added an exit animation to it. But when I click on ONE element, all of the other elements also play the exit animation. How can I prevent this from happening? I only want the div that got clicked playing the exit animation, not the other divs.

BTW: the hover animations do work individually. e.g. whileHover={{scale: 1.03}}

Small example of code:

```
{marvelMovies.map((movie, index) => 
   <motion.div exit={{opacity: 0}} transition={transition} className="movie" key={index}>
  
   
   </motion.div>
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you wrapping the divs in [Animate Presence](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animate-presence/)

```
<AnimatePresence>
{marvelMovies.map((movie, index) => 
   <motion.div exit={{opacity: 0}} transition={transition} className="movie" key={index} />)}
</AnimatePresence>
```

I made a code sandbox with a working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-multiple-item-animation-presence-sdmq2

Comment: This helped me, I had got confused trying to use "layoutId", but simplifying like so worked, thanks.